# Rust running on Windows I am battling with a basic error targeting X86 vs x64

Tags: rust

msvcrt.lib(chkstk.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. trying to run rust from developer powershell was causing the problem. In regular Windows PowerShell without path tweaks for Visual Studio, link.exe is not found in the command path, so cargo appears to magically discover the absolute path name in the x64 tools directory, which is the correct one. The host architecture of the shell does not affect this behavior.

Unfortunately, the launchers named Developer PowerShell and Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019 set up the command path for x86 tools. Perhaps it would be better for cargo to ignore the PATH-located executable on Windows if the registry-resolved tools directory appropriate for the target platform contains the executable file.